# Showing pdf preview in HTML body

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I don't know is it possible to do it, I want to know this and that's the reason I put this question on here. I'm still learning asp MVC and In my application, there is a part for users to upload attachments as image files or pdf files.

If the user attached image file, in the view It shows a small preview as shown here

[image]

This is the html code.

```
<td>
   <a href="@Url.Action("RetrieveImageG", new { id = item.Id })" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
   <img width="100" height="100" border="0" class="m1-1" align="center" src="@Url.Action("RetrieveImageG", new { id = item.Id })" />
   </a>
</td>
```

This is the attachment retrieving code in the controller.

```
public ActionResult RetrieveImageG(int id) {

  var q = from temp in db.GeneralItms where temp.Id == id select temp.Attachment;
  var type = from t in db.GeneralItms where t.Id == id select t.FileType;
  string fileType = type.First().ToString();
  byte[] cover = q.First();
  if (cover != null) {
    if (fileType == "pdf") {
      return File(cover, "pdf");
    } else {
      return File(cover, "image/jpg");
    }

  } else {
    return null;
  }

}
```

So my concern is, If the user attached the image file, requests details view this image preview area shows the preview as shown in the screenshot.

But If there is a pdf attached, the preview is shown as

[image]

Is there any way to show here the same as the image view for the pdf attachments also? Or else show pdf Icon even better, because by looking at the picture, the other user gets confused because if there isn't an attachment it also shows as the empty squire. Like the 2nd picture. Any solution for this matter?

Comment: Have you try to used embed pdf view?

Comment: @YasinSunni Not yet.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the information. I wanna know If is there any way, check if the attachment is not empty assign a pdf icon from the server location ? Then user can detect by viewing at the main view, there is a attachment available in the request.